# How can I turn a MOSFET into a diode?

Tags: mosfet

I have been reading about MOSFETs and the sub-threshold region.
From what I know about diodes, they have a set saturation current.

Would it be possible to bias a MOSFET to match the saturation current of a diode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enh. FETs have a (Vgs-Vt)^2/Ids impedance while diodes have a log Vf/If slope with a bulk Ri at rated current that approximates towards a linear curve above Vf@If max.

Apparently FETs made with this desired **sub-threshold characteristic will behave like diodes** in the low current region below gate threshold.

But you can't bias just any Enh. mode FET to behave this way. The log slope can be made to match a given diode characteristic by design, but that design is beyond the scope of this question which gets into "weak-inversion current reduction"

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subthreshold_conduction

Comment: what is an "Enh"?

Comment: Enhancement mode are the modern ones, depletion mode were the original ones